# ignore node using XSLT

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt

I have below xml file which is coming form my vendor.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <nm:MT_employee xmlns:nm="http://firstscenario.com"xmlns:tl="http://secondscenario.com">
   <EMployeeDetails>
  <Name>Janardhan</Name>
  <id>1234</id>
  <Address>India</Address>
   </EMployeeDetails>
<tl:Extension>
  <tl:Number>5678</tl:Number>
   <tl:Salary>2345678</tl:Salary>
   </tl:Extension>
   </nm:MT_employee>
```

In the above xml I want to ignore the entire **tl:Extension** node. the final output should be like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <nm:MT_employee xmlns:nm="http://firstscenario.com"xmlns:tl="http://secondscenario.com">
   <EMployeeDetails>
  <Name>Janardhan</Name>
  <id>1234</id>
  <Address>India</Address>
   </EMployeeDetails>
   </nm:MT_employee>
```

I tried to with different XSLT codes but it's not working. Could you please suggest how can I achieve this?

Regards,
Janardhan

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the most recent XSLT you have tried that is "not working"? It would also help if you said why it is not working (i.e are you getting an error, or is the output you get not what you expect). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general rule to "ignore" an element from the source XML
is to write an "empty" template for this element, in your case:

```
<xsl:template match="tl:Extension"/>
```

As this template refers to *tl* namespace, it must be specified
in the *xsl:transform* tag.

Of course, to copy the rest of the source content, your script
must include the *identity template*.

Below you have an example script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:tl="http://secondscenario.com" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="tl:Extension"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```